# How to see who created repository in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

There are some repositories on this page https://graphdb.sti2.at/ , how can see who have created which repository ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to tell who created which repository. There's a way to audit the user actions, which needs to be configured - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/security-auditing.html